# Keyboard shortcut for opening the layer properties window of the selected layer

Tags: qgis

As I sometimes have to do this quite often, I wonder if there's a 1-key shortcut to open the layer properties window for the selected layer in QGIS 3.34+:

[image]

I already know the <kbd>F6</kbd>  shortcut for opening the attribute table, and tested all <kbd>F{1-12}</kbd> keys but none is actually opening the layer properties.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set your own using `Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts`.

[image]

Search `layer properties` and select it from the search results, click `Change`, then press the key you wish to use. It will warn you if it is already in use.

[image]

Comment: Should the F9 key be the default. Btw, thanks for that tip!

Comment: I must have overwritten mine at some point because F9 does nothing for me :D

Comment: It actually does *nothing* ;) that's why it would be nice if it could be used as a default on a fresh QGIS install.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, I misinterpreted your comment. I used F10 for testing, That was also available.